While uploading a file to Ceph bucket , getting a S3 exception with code 403, after upgrading the s3 java dependency
While uploading a file to Ceph bucket , getting a S3 exception with code 403, after upgrading the s3 java dependency.
Error -
software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: tx000008156c10ec7e089e6-0067584294-5f946b5-ocs-storagecluster-cephobjectstore)
I have performed the below upgrade activity -
Spring boot : 2.5.0 -> 3.1.6
<artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId> 1.12.767 -> <artifactId>s3</artifactId> 2.29.30
refer - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3
With version <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId> 1.12.767 I was able to perform all the operations put/read/delete. After upgrading to <artifactId>s3</artifactId> 2.29.30  only able to successfully fetch the bucket name, not the put opration.
I was expecting to a successfull file upload as it was working with the previuos version, there is no any at my code level or infra side apart from this version upgrade.

généraly 403 mince you can reach the server but you do not have granted permissions to do some actions.
